# Can we Integrate third party video player in roku app?

Tags: android, roku, brightscript

I am working on a Roku app using scene graph component. Can I implement third party video player like "Azure Media Player" by any way in Roku application?

Third party video player developed with HTML, CSS and JavaScript code.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Not with HTML, CSS and JavaScript code. You can extend Video node and add any custom logic and ui you want. Also, you can wrap Video node in a Group node.

Extending:

```
<component name="MyVideoPlayer" extends="Video">

</component>
```

Wrapping:

```
<component name="MyVideoPlayer" extends="Group">

<children>
    <Video/>    
</children>

</component>
```